# Golang после изменения записи в таблице, возвращяет кэш

Tags: postgresql, golang

Не пойму почему go кэширует запрос,

Обновляю запись так:

```
func (r *DepartmentRepository) Update(d *model.Department) error {
    _, err := r.store.db.Exec(`update departments set title = $1 where id = $2`, d.Title, d.ID)
    if err .......

    return err
}
```

В базе запись обновилась. Затем получаю список так:

```
func (r *DepartmentRepository) List() ([]model.Department, error) {
    departments := []model.Department{}
    err := r.store.db.Select(&departments, `select id, title from departments`)
    if err .......

    return departments, err
}
```

но go почему то вытягивает старую запись. Если перезапустить сервер, вытягивается обновленная запись. Использую database/sqlx. База postgresql. В чем может быть проблема? Никаких кэшировании не настраивал

Comment: Пакета `database/sqlx` не существует.  Есть `database/sql` и `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`.  Плюс, из вопроса не понятно, как вы убеждаетесь, что запись старая.  Если вы смотрите HTML-вывод, то вполне мог закешироваться он.

Comment: да ошибся это github.com/jmoiron/sqlx, смотрю через Postman голый json, данные точно старые